# Contar nomes distintos salvos em txt

Tags: java, string, arquivo

Tenho um arquivo txt com nome de usuários separados por linha da forma abaixo:

```
diego
sergio
antonio
maria
diego
antonio
```

Percebam que nomes podem repetir, e gostaria de contar e listar apenas os nomes distintos.

Fiz este método para listar o arquivo todo:

```
String strPath = DIRETORIO + ARQUIVO_FILE;
if (pathExists(strPath)) {
    List<String> texto = Files.readAllLines(new File(strPath).toPath());
    for (String linha : texto) {
        System.out.println(linha);
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("arquivo não existe");
}
```

mas não estou sabendo como adapto ele em outro método que faça essa contagem de nomes distintos. Como faço essa contagem?

> Obs: alguns nomes podem vim com um ponto separando sobrenome tipo
>   `diego.felipe`, mas cada nome e/ou nome.sobrenome é gravado por linha
>   apenas.

Comment: Você quer, ao final de tudo, ter o número de total de nomes sem contar os repetidos, certo?

Comment: A primeira coisa que me veio a cabeça foi usar listas key-value, HashMap no Java por exemplo.

Comment: @jbueno exatamente isso

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Ok, fiz uma resposta com isso. Veja se lhe ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma lista de `strings` para salvar os nomes, valide se o nome já não existe dentro da lista antes de adicioná-lo, caso não exista, adicione o nome à lista. Ao final da iteração, use `lista.size()` para obter o somatório.

```
List<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();

String strPath = DIRETORIO + ARQUIVO_FILE;
if (pathExists(strPath)) 
{
    List<String> texto = Files.readAllLines(new File(strPath).toPath());
    for (String linha : texto) 
    {            
        if(!nomes.contains(linha)){
            nomes.add(linha);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Total de nomes: " + nomes.size());    

}
else 
{
    System.out.println("arquivo não existe");
}
```

Comment: Acho que me confundi no texto da pergunta, era pra contar o número total de vezes que nomes distintos aparecem na lista. De qualquer forma, o erro foi meu e a sua resposta atende ao respondido.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Essa implementação conta nomes distintos. O que está errado é apenas o texto do print. Note que ele verifica se tem o nome na lista antes de inserir. A única observação é que isso não é eficiente, pois o `contains` percorre a lista toda a cada chamada. A solução correta e eficiente é parecida com esta mas usando `HashSet`.

Comment: @utluiz na verdade eu me embolei ao fazer a pergunta, eu queria era contar as repetições e listar a contagem dos elementos distintos, como o jbueno já havia respondido dentro da pergunta como foi feita, e a segunda resposta me deu uma ideia de como resolver o verdadeira problema, acabei por marcando como resolvida. Foi como você desabafou no meta, ter a dúvida e não saber como perguntar :/

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Entendo. Mas não se acanhe, basta fazer outra pergunta. :D

Comment: @utluiz por coincidencia(ou sorte), uma das respostas daqui acabou me ajudando a resolver o problema, usei `hashmap` pra armazenar e contar os nomes e  repetições.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar a coleção [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), onde os elementos são mantidos de forma única. Caso você tente inserir um elemento já existente, o mesmo não é adicionado.

O interessante dessa coleção é que as operações básicas `add`, `remove`, `contains` e `size` possuem complexidade assintótica de `O(1)`.

```
HashSet<String> nomes = new HashSet<String>();

String strPath = DIRETORIO + ARQUIVO_FILE;
if (pathExists(strPath)) 
{
    List<String> texto = Files.readAllLines(new File(strPath).toPath());
    for (String linha : texto) 
    {   
        nomes.add(linha);
    }

    System.out.println("Total de nomes: " + nomes.size());    

}
else 
{
    System.out.println("arquivo não existe");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Olha não sei como funciona em Java. Mas no C# tem um conjunto chamado **HashSet** que não guarda elementos repetidos. De certa forma você vai precisar fazer algo desse tipo para Java.

```
HashSet<string> devedores = new HashSet<string>();
// Podemos adicionar elementos no conjunto utilizando o método Add
devedores.Add("victor");
devedores.Add("osni");

// Para sabermos o número de elementos adicionados, utilizamos a propriedade
// Count do conjunto. Nesse exemplo elementos guardará o valor 2
int elementos = devedores.Count;

// O conjunto não guarda elementos repetidos, então se tentarmos
// adicionar novamente a string "victor", o número de elementos
// continua sendo 2
devedores.Add("victor");
```

Comment: @jbueno por incrivel que pareça, pesquisei e o java também tem essa classe com este funcionamento.

Answer (score 0):

Dá para simplificar ainda mais a solução com `HashSet`, passando a `List` de leitura do arquivo direto para o construtor do `HashSet`:

```
String strPath = DIRETORIO + ARQUIVO_FILE;
if (pathExists(strPath)) {
    Set<String> nomes = new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(new File(strPath).toPath()));
    System.out.println("Total de nomes: " + nomes.size());    
} else {
    System.out.println("arquivo não existe");
}
```